# Can we have the variable in the script filled without have to request to form first?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, null

So I try to fill some table with data from a form and want to convert it to integer, but if i use `Integer.valueOf`, I must need to fill it first and I have problem with this

I tried to insert value in form but didn't work if I don't submit it first
is there a way i cant automatically fill one of this string parameter

```
<%
    String tanggal = request.getParameter("tanggal");
    String gp = request.getParameter("gajiPokok");
    Integer resultgp = Integer.valueOf(gp);
    String jk = request.getParameter("jumlahKehadiran");
    String b = request.getParameter("bolos");
    Integer resultb = Integer.valueOf(b);
    String d = request.getParameter("denda");
    Integer resultd = Integer.valueOf(d);
    String tt = request.getParameter("tunjanganTransport");
    Integer resulttt = Integer.valueOf(tt);
    String bp = request.getParameter("bonusPencapaian");
    Integer resultbp = Integer.valueOf(bp);
    Integer tgk = resultgp+resultbp+resulttt;
    Integer pth = resultb * resultd;
    Integer tbpjs = (resultgp+resultbp+resulttt-pth)*3/100;
    Integer tgb = (resultgp+resultbp+resulttt-pth)-tbpjs;
%>
```

Comment: If you want to process data entered into form without submitting it you need to use JavaScript. JSPs render server-side, so you need to use JavaScript that works on client-side.

Comment: no, what i want is to that script have temporary value

Comment: So your request has the parameters you are using in this script, but the script can't get the values?

Comment: that's kinda the issue, so i want to know if there's a way to temporary fill the variable here

Comment: What do you mean by temporary value? Where are the values coming from

Comment: i mean i have to table, one is form to input, and the other one is the one that i post here, in order the second form to get the values i have to press submit button in the first table, the second table can't get the data, and that's what make it a problem for the Integer.valueOf, because the data can't be null, so i just wondering if there's a way around this

Comment: Just check if its null and assign it a value of 0 instead, before trying to get the Integer value. You should write your Java code in class files (I assume you use controllers of some sort), but it also works in scriptlets.

Comment: thx for ur help but i just resolve it with simple if situation

Comment: Thats what I meant you should do, but still if possible don't process values in scriptlets, keep it to Java class files and just pass the processed values to JSP.

Comment: Improved formatting and text errors